# C# cannot add value to dictionary but the value doesn't exists already

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, equals

I have created a dictionary and try to add some values. These values are the input properties of our generated code:

```
_inputParameterMapping = new Dictionary<IVariable, IExpression>();
```

I have to add **three** values, but the dictionary gives me the following error:

> 'An item with the same key has already been added'

When I compare these values they are not equal to each other. (See the attachments 1 and 2). In the attachment you will see that the **memberNames** of both keys are different from each other.

[image]
[image]

The **HashCodes** of both keys are equal to each other, but the objects aren't and the Equals function result in 'true' (see attachment 3)
[image]

This is my function:

```
public StoredProcedureCall(IStoredProcedureDeclaration storedProcedure, params IExpression[] inputValues)
{
    if (storedProcedure == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("storedProcedure");

    if (inputValues.Length > storedProcedure.InputParameters.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("inputValues length does not match function.InputParameters length");

    _storedProcedure = storedProcedure;
    _inputValues = inputValues;

    _inputParameterMapping = new Dictionary<IVariable, IExpression>();
    for (var i = 0; i < _inputValues.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!storedProcedure.InputParameters[i].ParameterType.IsInstanceOfType(_inputValues[i]))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("inputArgument {0} type ({1}) is not same as inputParameter '{2}' type ({3}) in stored procedure '{4}'",
                i,
                ReflectionUtils.GetTypeNameWithoutNameSpaceQualifiers(_inputValues[i].Type.GetType()),
                storedProcedure.InputParameters[i].Template.MemberName,
                ReflectionUtils.GetTypeNameWithoutNameSpaceQualifiers(storedProcedure.InputParameters[i].ParameterType),
                _storedProcedure.MemberName));
        }

        _inputParameterMapping.Add(storedProcedure.InputParameters[i].Template, _inputValues[i]);
    }
}
```

How should this problem occurs and why the dictionary thinks these properties are equal to each other?

Thank you in advanced!

Kind regards,
Jelle

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're adding the value to the dictionary please? The problem is probably to do with how you're passing the Key, not the value.

Comment: If IVariable.Equals returns true, the two objects are identical, by definition.

Comment: I have add the function. The key in the watch is the existing key in the dictionary.

Comment: Did you override ``Equals()`` and ``GetHashCode()`` appropriately in your implementation deriving from ``IVariable``?

Answer (score 0):

> The HashCodes of both keys are equal to each other

that is the problem, because

> the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table. -[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

and uses the GetHashCode-function as the default Hashing-Algorithm.

**Solution 1**

Override GetHashCode (and Equal) for your IVariable implementation and add the MemberNameto it:

```
override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode() | MemberName.GetHashCode();
}
```

*This is a basic solution and ignores all other members of the IVariable interface*

**Solution 2**

> If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation

Implement the [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface

```
public bool Equals(IVariable other)
{
    if(this.MemberName!= other.MemberName)
         return false;

    //... Compare other members ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you have a problem with you object comparison. Your dirctionary dont realy know how to compare you key objects. I would recomment to implement IEqualityComparer and use it for the dictionary. Take a look at my sample:

```
    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        var one = new SomeClass(10);
        var two = new SomeClass(200);
        var three = new SomeClass(10); //same value as object "one"

        var myComparer = new SomeClassComparer();
        var myDictionary = new Dictionary<SomeClass, object>(myComparer);
        myDictionary.Add(one, "Some Data");
        myDictionary.Add(two, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
        // causes exceptions even if InitializationTime differs because of SomeClass.ImportantValue comparison 
        myDictionary.Add( three, new List<object>() );
    }
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int ImportantValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime InitializationTime { get; set; }
        public SomeClass(int value)
        {
            ImportantValue = value;
            //every object gets its "unique" InitializationTime
            InitializationTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public class SomeClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
    {
        public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
        {
            //do comparison of data that represents the identity of the objects data
            return x.ImportantValue.Equals(y.ImportantValue);
        }
        public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
        {
            //calculate a hash code from data that represents the identity of the objects data
            return (obj.ImportantValue).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```